# Google Bigquery: Retain Previous Value of Column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 columns named claim_no & n Proc_rank.Trying to use below logic.Please help here

Logic

```
a) if  claim_no=proc_rank then linenum=1
b) if  claim_no<>proc_rank then a+1
c) if  claim_no=proc_rank then value of b
d) if  claim_no<>proc_rank then c+1
```

I tried with Lag Function with case statement, but not getting desired results & recursive queries not supported by Google Big query.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 1 + COUNTIF(claim_no != n_Proc_rank) OVER(ORDER BY ts) linenum
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ts, 1 claim_no, 1 n_Proc_rank UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 16, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 17, 0, 1 
)
SELECT *, 1 + COUNTIF(claim_no != n_Proc_rank) OVER(ORDER BY ts) linenum
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY ts
```

result is

```
Row ts  claim_no    n_Proc_rank linenum  
1   1   1           1           1    
2   2   0           0           1    
3   3   0           0           1    
4   4   1           1           1    
5   5   0           1           2    
6   6   0           0           2    
7   7   0           1           3    
8   8   0           1           4    
9   9   0           1           5    
10  10  0           1           6    
11  11  0           0           6    
12  12  0           1           7    
13  13  0           0           7    
14  14  0           1           8    
15  15  0           1           9    
16  16  0           1           10   
17  17  0           1           11
```

Note: you must have some extra column that defines order or processing, so in my example I added column ts. It can be anything - integer position or date/timestamp, etc.